# Don't escape the special characters in the Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, windows, r-markdown, knitr

In my Rmarkdown file, there are some special characters I don't want to escape in the chunks (e.g. `<` and `>`).

This is a minimum example to show my problem.

---

````
title: "test-special-character"
output: md_document
date: "2022-12-02"
---

```{r test-special-character, results='asis'}
cat("<$htmlwidgets />")
```
````

The output in the md file is

```
&lt;$htmlwidgets /&gt;
```

What I expect is

```
<$htmlwidgets />
```

So my question is how I should not escape the special character in the Rmarkdown file.

I am using R 4.2.0 in Windows 10 with knitr 1.39 and rmarkdown 2.14.

Comment: I can see the `<>` after rendering. Try update your software first, R4.2.0=>R4.2.2, knitr 1.39=>knitr1.40, rmarkdwon 2.14=>rmarkdown 2.17.

Comment: Thanks. I still have the same problem for R 4.4.2, knitr 1.41, rmarkdown 2.18.

Comment: How exactly do you render the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have to use `cat`, you could try this

````
```{r, results='asis'}
knitr::raw_html("<$htmlwidgets />")
```
````

Comment: BTW, using `{=html}` might be simpler if the string is not generated from R code: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-content.html (`knitr::raw_html()` is simply a wrapper for `{=html}`)